# No unit test run since migration to VS2019

Tags: visual-studio

Previously, we were using Visual Studio 2017.
We've recently migrate to use Visual Studio 2019.

Every unit test is correctly discovered by VS2019 but, when we cannot run them. It sais that tests takes some time to execute (0.6s or 1.8s for example) but they don't produce any result and it don't reach any break points.

We tried to add MsTest.Adapter and NUnit3TestAdapter without any change.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what to do (or at least what can make it works) :
We removed every test package (MSTest.Adapter and NUnit3ATestAdapter) and add a direct reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll)

Now, every test works fine (even if the ouput is awful)